# Multiple markers at this line(C++) Regarding function

Tags: c++, coverity

I'm getting the above error in my code.

File Scope Prototypes

```
static void pressure_val_update(void);
```

The above prototype is been used in below function

```
void ui_vcr_menu_update(const MENU_CONTROL_T *p, UINT8 HAL)
{
    pressure_val_update();
    ratio_val_update();
    pressure_unit_update();
}
```

Below is the function definition

```
static void pressure_val_update(void)
{
    UINT8 fl_pressure_value_U8;

    /* Get the  Pressure value from RTE */
    Rte_Read_rpVCRDisplayValue_Pressure(&fl_pressure_value_U8);

    /* Case 1 : Step 0 - Step 16 */
    if(fl_pressure_value_U8 < 17U)
    {
        l_pressure_value_S16 = (-270 + (fl_pressure_value_U8 * 5.4));
        rbmp_U8 = DISABLE
        l_pressure_lbbmp_U8 = IMAGE_ENABLE;
        l_pressure_ltbmp_U8 = DISABLE
    }
    /* Case 2 : Step 17 - Step 33 */
    else if((fl_pressure_value_U8 >= 17U) && (fl_pressure_value_U8 < 34U))
    {
        l_pressure_value_S16 = (-270 + (fl_pressure_value_U8 * 5.4));
        rbmp_U8 = DISABLE
        l_pressure_lbbmp_U8 = IMAGE_ENABLE;
        l_pressure_ltbmp_U8 = IMAGE_ENABLE;
    }
    /* Case 3 : Step 34 - Step 50 */
    else if((fl_pressure_value_U8 >= 34U) && (fl_pressure_value_U8 < 51U))
    {
        l_pressure_value_S16 = (-270 + (fl_pressure_value_U8 * 5.4));
        rbmp_U8 = IMAGE_ENABLE;
        l_pressure_lbbmp_U8 = IMAGE_ENABLE;
        l_pressure_ltbmp_U8 = IMAGE_ENABLE;
    }
    else
    {
        l_pressure_value_S16 = -270;
        rbmp_U8 = DISABLE
        l_pressure_lbbmp_U8 = DISABLE
        l_pressure_ltbmp_U8 = DISABLE
    }
}
/*
```

How to solve this, Why do it get multiple markers at this line (`static void pressure_val_update(void)`).

I am working application projects and facing this issue.

I have gone through other internet solutions but those are not related to me.

Please let me know the exact reason why we will get this warning (I got this warning in coverity analysis)

Comment: Please try to build your program, then copy the full and complete output of the compiler (copy as text) and edit your question to include the pasted output.

Comment: "multiple markers at this line" does not look like an actual warning text, static analysis tools typically generate proper detection reports with all the details. You should look for this report and post it here if warning source is still unclear.

Comment: DEADCODE - pressure_val_update(Function) 
di.build.Imhotep.cmfb.ic.ui\Menu\View\src\ui_vcr_menu_presentation.- Multiple markers at this line(warning)

Comment: This just means there are multiple errors on the line, it gives us no indication what those errors are. Since the line itself looks okay to me, my first suspicion would be that you've missed a semi-colon or close-bracket on one of the previous lines, but we cannot see if this is the case because you haven't posted an MVCE.